# Table control does not display all rows

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a problem where not all of the rows of my table control are being displayed in ABAP 740 SP13.

For example, I have a table with these two rows:

[image: Values of LT_TRANSFER_CONFIRM_TC]

This is the state of the table where this code is executed:

```
CALL SCREEN 0300 STARTING AT 10 5
                 ENDING AT 85 16.
```

This goes immediately into my Process Before Output code:

```
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*                        PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT                         *
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  MODULE status_0300.
  LOOP AT lt_transfer_confirm_tc
         INTO ls_transfer_confirm_tc
         WITH CONTROL tc_transfer_confirm
         CURSOR tc_transfer_confirm-current_line.
    MODULE tc_transfer_confirm_get_lines.
  ENDLOOP.
```

where `status_0300` is:

```
MODULE status_0300 OUTPUT.
  SET PF-STATUS 'STATUS_0300'.
  " Confirm Material Number Count
  SET TITLEBAR 'T05'.
ENDMODULE.
```

and is `tc_transfer_confirm_get_lines`:

```
MODULE tc_transfer_confirm_get_lines OUTPUT.
  g_tc_transfer_confirm_lines = sy-loopc.
ENDMODULE.
```

At the end of the first iteration of the loop in my PBO, the `ls_transfer_confirm_tc` value matches with the first row of the `lt_transfer_confirm_tc` table, `tc_transfer_confirm-current_line` is `1`, and `g_tc_transfer_confirm_lines` (in `tc_transfer_confirm_get_lines`) is set to `10`.

The second iteration of the loop never processes. The cursor hops from `ENDLOOP` (from the first iteration) to the line saying `CURSOR tc_transfer_confirm-current_line.` (as it is the end of the `LOOP` statement), and finally to `ENDLOOP` without stopping on the `MODULE tc_transfer_confirm_get_lines` line. At the end of this loop, `ls_transfer_confirm_tc` is initial, `tc_transfer_confirm-current_line` is still `1`, and `g_tc_transfer_confirm_lines` is still `10`. All the while, the `lt_transfer_confirm_tc` table still has two rows in it as shown in the image at the top of this question.

At this point, the screen is displayed as follows:

[image: Table Control displayed by SCREEN 0300]

I'm not sure why this loop doesn't process the second row of my table, and therefore doesn't display it on the screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was never setting the value of `tc_transfer_confirm-lines`, so that the value was always 1.

The following code runs successfully:

```
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*                        PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT                         *
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  MODULE status_0300.
  MODULE tc_trnsfr_cnfrm_change_tc_attr.
  LOOP AT lt_transfer_confirm_tc
         INTO ls_transfer_confirm_tc
         WITH CONTROL tc_transfer_confirm
         CURSOR tc_transfer_confirm-current_line.
    MODULE tc_transfer_confirm_get_lines.
  ENDLOOP.
```

With the new module `tc_trnsfr_cnfrm_change_tc_attr`:

```
*&SPWIZARD: OUTPUT MODULE FOR TC 'TC_TRANSFER_CONFIRM'. DO NOT CHANGE THIS LINE!
*&SPWIZARD: UPDATE LINES FOR EQUIVALENT SCROLLBAR
MODULE tc_trnsfr_cnfrm_change_tc_attr OUTPUT.
  DESCRIBE TABLE lt_transfer_confirm_tc LINES tc_transfer_confirm-lines.
ENDMODULE.
```